# Continue a Do-Until loop until someone put something different than 1 to 9

Tags: powershell

The problem is that the loop is working the first time but it stops after and I want it to continue like this until the input is different than 1 to 9.

```
do
{
    Show-Menu
    $selection = Read-Host "Please choose an option"
    switch ($selection)
    {
        '1' {
            Get-ChildItem
        } '2' {
            get-host|Select-Object
        } '3' {
            Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed
        } '4' {
            Get-NetRoute
        } '5' {
            Get-DnsClientCache
        } '6' {
            Get-Date -UFormat "%A %B/%d/%Y %T %Z"
        } '7' {
            Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\
        } '8' {
            Stop-Service -Name Spooler -Force
            Restart-Service -Name Spooler -Force
        } '9' {
            Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"}
        }
    }
    pause
}
until ($selection -ne 1..9)
```

I tried a while loop but it did an infinite loop...

Comment: You're looking for `-notin` instead of `-ne`

Answer (score 1):

The only issue with your code is the use of `-ne`:

```bash
until ($selection -ne 1..9)
```

Instead of `-notin`:

```bash
until ($selection -notin 1..9)
```

---

[`-notin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators) is meant to compare if a scalar (a single value) in the LHS (left-hand side) **is not present** in a collection on the RHS (right-hand side), `$selection -notin 1..9` will return `$true` when `$selection` is other than `1` to `9`.

On the other hand [`-ne`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#equality-operators) is mostly meant to test inequality, even though it can work as a filter when the LHS is a collection, i.e.:

```bash
'foo', 'bar', 'baz' -ne 'foo' # => 'bar', 'baz'
```

However as you had it before, you were testing if a single value (`$selection`) was not equal to an array (`1..9`) which will always be `$true` hence your loop ended after its first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you could have done this.

```
function Show-Menu
{
    Param()

    $selection = Read-Host 'Please choose an option'

    switch ($selection)
    {
        '1' {
            Get-ChildItem
        } '2' {
            get-host|Select-Object
        } '3' {
            Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed
        } '4' {
            Get-NetRoute
        } '5' {
            Get-DnsClientCache
        } '6' {
            Get-Date -UFormat '%A %B/%d/%Y %T %Z'
        } '7' {
            Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\
        } '8' {
            Stop-Service -Name Spooler -Force
            Restart-Service -Name Spooler -Force
        } '9' {
            Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Running'}
        }
    }    
}
do {Show-Menu}
until ($selection -match '1-9')

# Results
<#
Please choose an option: 0
Please choose an option: 10
Please choose an option: 20
Please choose an option: 11
Please choose an option: 4

# Results
<#
ifIndex DestinationPrefix                              NextHop                                  RouteMetric ifMetric PolicyStore
...
#>
```

The way your code block is written now, even with the prudent correction offered by 'Santiago Squarzon', it would still exit on numbers not in that array.

Here's what I mean.

```
do
{
    Show-Menu
    $selection = Read-Host "Please choose an option"
    switch ($selection)
    {
        '1' {
            Get-ChildItem
        } '2' {
            get-host|Select-Object
        } '3' {
            Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed
        } '4' {
            Get-NetRoute
        } '5' {
            Get-DnsClientCache
        } '6' {
            Get-Date -UFormat "%A %B/%d/%Y %T %Z"
        } '7' {
            Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\
        } '8' {
            Stop-Service -Name Spooler -Force
            Restart-Service -Name Spooler -Force
        } '9' {
            Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"}
        }
    }
}
until ($selection -notin  1..9)
# Results
<#
until ($selection -notin  1..9)
Please choose an option: 0
Please choose an option: 10
# the do exited

until ($selection -notin  1..9)
Please choose an option: 11
Please choose an option: 110
# the do exited
#>
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you need a While loop. The Do itself does nothing.

You also need an exit condition to break out of the loop. Try

```
switch(...)
{
<# switch options #>
default {break}
}
```

Comment: Your answer is completely inaccurate

Comment: The `do` statement in the question is well-formed and is _not_ the problem _per se_; see  [about_Do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Do).

Comment: I did, again, for clarity: "The Do keyword works with the While keyword or the Until keyword" .... Dunno how it could could loop anything like this, but fine.

Comment: Also, a `break` statement inside a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement does _not_ exit an _enclosing loop_ (whatever form that loop takes - `foreach`, `while`, or `do`).